# React/Typescript Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & [Interface]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a Component where I am accessing a local json file and passing the array of objects to another component.

Code snippet for the **first component** -

import statement -
`import TvData from './Data/TVData.json';`

for the second component I am passing the data like so,
I am getting the **Error** for this line saying

```
Type '{ data: { id: number; name: string; price: number; imageUrl: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & dataProps'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & dataProps'.
```

`<SecondComponent data={TvData} />`

Code Snippet for the **second component** -

here I defined interface like so,

```
interface dataProp {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price : number;
    imageUrl : string;
}
type dataProps = dataProp[];
```

and the functional Component with parameters like so,

`function SecondComponent(data: dataProps)`

inside which I am mapping through the array of objects from the json file

```
{
  data.map((item : dataProp) =>
   {
    return (
     <Item key={item.id}>
        {item.name}
      </Item>
           )
    }
  )}
```

I am new to React with Typescript so any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

component props must be an object, not an array. Try putting the array inside of one of the input props, like this:

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price : number;
    imageUrl : string;
}
type Props = { data: Item[] };

...

function SecondComponent(props: Props) {
  return props.data.map(item => (
     <Item key={item.id}>
        {item.name}
      </Item>
    ));
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much! this helped greatly

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted, if it resolved your issue